# WHERE IN query - Is not supported by BigQuery or Resources exceeded

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table like

```
header: source,  user, metric1, metric2,...
data:
source1, user1, metrics..
source1, user2, metrics..
source2, user1, metrics..
source3, user1, metrics...
source3, user3, metrics...
```

...

And I would like to aggregate some metrics for users which are not found for each source.
On example above I would like to extract for source2: users2 and user3 and get avg or their metrics.

Looking into something like:

```
select avg(metric1) from tbl as tbl1
where user is not in 
  (select user from tbl as tbl2 where tbl1.source=tbl2.source)
group by source
```

The query above doesnot works in Legacy SQL as per documentation page:
(https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql)
but does in ANSI, however I got `Resources exceeded`

Comment: If you post a job id the Google guys can dig a little deeper for you

Comment: even though you gave expected "logic" for source2, i still see many ways to interpret this! Can you provide expectations for source1 and source3 too? it might eliminate uncertainty!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - not sure what you mean. I am trying to join the table on it's own on one field named _source_.

I.e. I need to find all users (unique value for _user_ field) than find all rows for each of just finded users and get average for all those rows over _metric1_ field

Comment: but you also mentioned "... for users which are not found for each source..." this makes it a little fuzzy. So that's why i asked you to give expected output for source1 and source3 - this can clarify what exactly you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually using WHERE IN / NOT IN is not considered a good practice if number of records returned by the inner SELECT is large. Try to rewrite your query using LEFT OUTER JOIN like

`select tbl1.source as source, avg(tbl1.metric1) as avg_metric1
from tbl as tbl1
left outer join tbl as tbl2 on tbl1.source = tbl2.source
where tbl2.user is null
group by source`

Comment: thank you @Dmitri Safine very much. The query works however on 30 mln of rows I interrupted in after 10k seconds without waiting till its finished.